# When scaling, the start coordinates change

Tags: python, pygame

I dynamically scale an image. It is working. In the example, I set the image center to (300,300). That doesn't work. the image will appear in the upper left corner. why?

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
  
size = width,height = 600, 600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size) 
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

class Fireball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):       
    def __init__(self,x,y,w,h):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)     
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Bilder/fireball.png") 
        self.img = self.image      
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()       
        self.rect.centerx , self.rect.centery= x,y
        self.w ,self.h = w, h
   
    def update(self):
        self.w += 2
        self.h += 2
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.img,(int(self.w),int(self.h)))
        self.image.set_alpha(10+ self.h * 5)
      
fireball = Fireball(300,300,10,10) 

alle_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group() 
fireball_sprites = pygame.sprite.Group()
fireball_sprites.add(fireball)
alle_sprites.add(fireball)

running = True  
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
    alle_sprites.update()
    alle_sprites.draw(screen)
    pygame.display.flip()
    clock.tick(30)
```

Answer (score 1):

As the image resizes, you need to update the bounding rectangle and set the center of the bounding rectangle to the center of the original rectangle:

```py
class Fireball(pygame.sprite.Sprite):  
    # [...]

    def update(self):
        self.w += 2
        self.h += 2

        center = self.rect.center
        self.image = pygame.transform.scale(self.img,(int(self.w),int(self.h)))
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = center)

        self.image.set_alpha(10+ self.h * 5)
```